# plsql - get first row - which one is better?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
LV_id number;
Cursor CR_test Is
  select t.id
  from table1 t
  where t.foo = p_foo
  order by t.creation_date; 

Open CR_test;
Fetch CR_test
 Into LV_id;
Close CR_test;
```

or this one :

```
select x.id
from(select t.id
     from table1 t
     where t.foo=p_foo
     order by t.creation_date) x
where rownum = 1
```

Both above make similar result but i need known about which one is more efficient!

Answer (score 8):

This is Tom Kyte's mantra:

> You should do it in a single SQL statement if at all possible.
>   If you cannot do it in a single SQL Statement, then do it in PL/SQL.
>   If you cannot do it in PL/SQL, try a Java Stored Procedure.
>   If you cannot do it in Java, do it in a C external procedure.
>   If you cannot do it in a C external routine, you might want to seriously think about why it is you need to do it…

http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2006/10/slow-by-slow.html

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to find out in this case is to test your queries.

**Make sure to test this yourself, indexes and data in your table may produce different results with your table.**

Without any index, it looks like there is a better approach using analytic function [DENSE_RANK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions043.htm):

```
SELECT MIN(id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY creation_date)
INTO lv_id
FROM table1
WHERE foo = p_foo;
```

---

I used the following code to test the time consumed by your queries (execute this block several times, results may vary):

```
DECLARE
  p_foo  table1.foo%TYPE := 'A';
  lv_id  table1.id%TYPE;
  t      TIMESTAMP := SYSTIMESTAMP;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. 100 LOOP
    -- Query here
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line(SYSTIMESTAMP - t);
END;
```

---

Results:

1. Using cursor, fetching first row:
   **2.241 s**
2. Using query with `ROWNUM`:
   **1.483 s**
3. Using `DENSE_RANK`:
   **1.168 s**